# I need a code for my ford focus radio 6000CD - SECURITY CODED!

Tags: ford, audio, code

[image: code for my ford radio sanyo automedia]

Please help me, I need a code for my ford radio

Serial number: 24640690091
SAM MODEL NO. 14790921

Answer (score 2):

You serial number is 246406900921 not 24640690091, try **1488** code found on this website - https://fordradiocode.eu/